# Python/Selenium - find element by xpath - element there, but not found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a website with the following items:

```
<input type="text" style="width:230px;" name="email"></input>
```

and

```
<input type="password" style="width:230px;" name="password"></input>
```

With the following python code trying to set values (know username and password are set earlier in code):

```
Helper.getElementByxPath(mydriver,'//*[@name="email"]',username);
Helper.getElementByxPath(mydriver,'//*[@type="password"]',password);
```

And Helper.getElementByxPath is defined as:

```
def getElementByxPath(mydriver,xPath,valueString):
    try:
        a = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath);
        a.send_keys(valueString);
        return 1;
    except:
        return 0;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Unexpected error: <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>
Unexpected error: <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>
```

What am I possibly doing wrong here? Banging my head against a wall.

---

I am an idiot, my desired form was embedded in a frame. Within a frame.

Comment: The elements could be in a `frame` or `iframe`.  If the elements are in a frame/iframe, you can use `switch_to_frame(IDENTIFIER)`, where IDENTIFIER is the frame name, the frame webelement, or the index of the frame.  Or it could be that the elements are loading slowly or after the page completes loading.

Comment: thanks will look into `switch_to_frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your elements are in a `frame`, you can use

```
driver.switch_to_frame(IDENTIFIER)
```

IDENTIFIER can be
- Frame name
- Frame webelement
- Frame index

API reference here:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Once you're finished in the frame, you can return to the top of the document as follows:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```